# Transient and Scoped services consuming a singleton data source

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to learn dependency inversion and IOC. In the process, I have hit a wall.

This is what I understand about DI principle -> high-level classes are based on abstractions and not implementations.

All good.

So keeping the above in mind. I have the following example.

```
public interface IServiceA
{
   public void DoSomething();
}

public class ServiceA : IServiceAInterface
{
   IDataInterface dataSource;
   DataSourceType data;

   // omitted config injectino for brevity
   public ServiceA(IDataInterface _data)
   {
            dataSource = _dataSource;
            var dataSourceName = config.GetValue<string>("DataSourceName"); 
            data = dataSource.GetDataSource(dataSourceName);
   }

   public void doSomething()
   {
      data.doSomething();
   }
}
```

```
public interface IDataInterface
{
    public DataSourceType getDataSource(string ds);
}

public class DataAccessService : IDataInterface
{
        public DataSourceType GetDataSource(string dataSource)
        {
            if (dataSource == "InApp")
            {
                var source = new DataSourceType();
                return source;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

The above is a service class which needs data to perform tasks which it gets from `DataAccessService`.

Now I am using an application class/model for persistence throughout the app lifetime. Therefore I have registered it as a singleton.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ---
    services.AddSingelton<IDataInterface,DataAccessService>();
    service.AddScoped<IServieAInterface,ServiceA>();
    ---
}
```

This does not work.

I hypothesize it is because, the parent service (service A) has a lesser lifetime than the child service (`DataAccessService`).

I have understood through this that service A is responsible for instantiation of the object.

However, I expected the IOC container to instantiate only one `DataAccessService` object and inject it to all services that need this.

Not sure why my assumption is wrong.

Based on the above hypothesis I tried the following:

```
public interface IDataInterface
{
}

public class DataAccessService : IDataInterface
{
    public DataSourceType dataSource;

    public DataAccessService(string ds)
    {
        if (ds == "InApp")
        {
            this.dataSource = new DataSourceType();
        }
        else
        {
            this.dataSource = null;
        }
    }
}

public class ServiceA: DataAccessService,IServceAInterface
{
    DatSourceTye data;
  
    public ServiceA():base("InApp")
    {
        config = _config;
        data = dataSource;
    }

    public void doSomething()
    {
      data.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
// Hoping to pass parameter through startup
services.AddSingleton<IDataInterface>(x =>
            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DataAccessService>(x, "InApp")
        );
service.AddScoped<IServieAInterface,ServiceA>();
```

I hoped the above would work, as here the `DataAccessService` is responsible for initialization.

But still a new `DataAccessService` object is created for every class.

I think, I have messed up my understanding about how the life times work.
need help on this.

Also, what I am trying to achieve is a singleton data source on which different services act on throughout the application lifetime.

Transient and scoped services consuming a singleton data source. I think this should be possible

Is there something bad in terms of design in what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: It is entirely possible, and you need to be **explicit** in what actually happens. Transient and Scoped can consume singleton services but not the other way around. It's not only possible, it's extremely common. Please [edit] this and include a [mre].

Comment: Would be good if you add the error message..

Comment: not getting any error, a new instance is obtained every request.
let me edit the question with some more code :)

Comment: here I am registering DataAccessService as  a Singelton class, rest as Transient,
but the ApplicationDataSource class keeps getting re-instantiated every request, because of which I am getting new objects every request.

However, making everything singelton works good.

Comment: Found my mistake, the problem was -> I was using a Data Service to obtain an instance of the data source. This service was constructor injected. However, to obtain the datasource from the service I was actually instantiating the data source class manually in one of the service methods.
Because of this, though the service was singleton, every time I called its GetDataSource method, this was giving me a new instance.

Will close the question , ty :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public DataAccessService(string ds)
    {
        if (ds == "InApp")
        {
            this.dataSource = new DataSourceType();
        }
        else
        {
            this.dataSource = null;
        }
    }
```

This method in the data service was being called every time, I needed the data source.
As this method is instantiating another class manually, though the service is singleton,
every time the above method - DataAccessService was called , I was getting a new instance.